# Windows Phone 8.1 Developer Preview FM Radio got the 'white sound'

Tags: 8.1, nokia-lumia-920

I'm using Nokia Lumia 920, when I'm turning on the FM Radio in my windows phone, then I change the frequency that I want to listen, then I just can't listen clearly instead of there're the "white sound" (the sound is like ssssaaaa, similar to the tv sound that you can't find the frequency). Before I updating to the Windows Phone 8.1 Developer Preview, I've no problem with that, after I updated to Windows Phone 8.1, I just didn't use for the FM Radio for 2-3 months, just today, when I turn on the FM Radio and listened the "white sound", but I can heard a little bit of the people talking or playing the song in that frequency, but the sound mostly covered with the "white sound". So anyone face this problem with me? Or anyone know how to fix this problem? I hope you guys can help me a lot and can fix this as soon as possible or else I'm wait for the Official Windows Phone 8.1. Appreciate for those who help me on this. Thanks.

Comment: What app are you using?

Comment: @RowlandShaw The built-in FM Radio apps. It comes with windows phone.

Comment: I don't have that app installed on my (8.0) device, only on an 820 running 8.1, which works fine. How are you tuning? Are you using the scan buttons?

Comment: Also, do you have something plugged into the headphone socket?

Comment: @RowlandShaw I did tune to the correct frequency which can be listen by the car's radio or others radio as well. Besides that, I'm also using the original Lumia 920 earphone to listen it. But it still playing those white sound(sssaaaaa sound) to me.